# Excel 2010: How to display a value in cents as dollars by using only cell formatting, not formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Let's say I have an integer value of 950 (representing 950 cents) in cell A1 in an Excel 2010 spreadsheet. Is there a way to make Excel *display* this value as 9.50 (representing 9.50 dollars) in that same cell (A1) while still keeping the original integer value as 950, maybe by using a custom number format code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Number format code you want is

```
#0\.00
```

The hash (#) is for optional extra digits and the slash (\) before the decimal point (.) makes it a literal text character instead of the default decimal point position marker. Zeroes (0) will display a zero regardless of how many digits there are in the number.